# defined macro locations in excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros, location

I have a 120+ sheet workbook, the front page of which has a nice function to extract a specified sheet, saving it as a new book with a bunch of details. Which all works fine. Trying to add a new function though. On the extracted sheet, I've added a button and created a macro that will e-mail the finished article. The problem is, the location reference for the macro keeps defaulting back to the original book source, rather than the sheet itself (its all .XLSM files). The macro itself is on each sheet, but I can't find a way of fixing the reference for the macro to the sheet proper. And my google-fu has failed me. Any input or words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

OK, here's the mailer macro:

```
Sub Mail_FinishedSheet_Array()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim StrBody As String

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
        If wb1.FileFormat = 51 And wb1.HasVBProject = True Then
            MsgBox "There is VBA code in this xlsx file. There will" & vbNewLine & _
                   "be no VBA code in the file you send. Save the" & vbNewLine & _
                   "file as a macro-enabled (. Xlsm) and then retry the macro.", vbInformation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Signature details with path
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
            "\Microsoft\Signatures\Zonal2014HO.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    ' Make a copy of the file.
    ' If you want to change the file name then change only TempFileName variable.
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = wb1.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy hh-mm")
    FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, _
                                   Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))

    wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    'Body contents for HTML format e-mail
    StrBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Hi," _
    & "<p>Please find a completed checksheet attached for a PC Rebuild." _
    & "<p>Regards, " _
    & "<p></BODY>"

   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run this procedure.
    With OutMail
        .To = "Eng_Tech_support@zonal.co.uk"
        .CC = "rob.brown@zonal.co.uk"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Completed PC Rebuild Checksheet " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
        .HTMLbody = StrBody & Signature
        .Attachments.Add wb2.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Delete the file.
    ' Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

And here's the extraction macro from the main page that seperates the desires sheet from the book and saves it as a new file:

```
Sub Full_Extract()

Dim wbkOriginal As Workbook
Set wbkOriginal = ActiveWorkbook

'sets site and engineer details into the estate page that is being extracted
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("E6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("N6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("F3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("F8")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D4").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K8")

' copies sheet name from combo box into new document, saves it with site name and current date
' into C:\Temp\ folder for ease of access

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array((Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value), "Z-MISC"))
            .Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            "C:\temp\" _
            & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(3, 2).Text _
            & " " _
            & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
            & ".xlsm", _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With

'code to close the original workbook to prevent accidental changes etc
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkOriginal.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ah... only if there was some  code along with this. some times they are helpful.

Comment: The macro for the mailer is fairly common, and it physically works (if I don't extract one of the sheets and just run it, it does everything its supposed to do) its just once the sheet is extracted, the location the button is pointing to becomes 'Checkbook.xlsm'!activesheet.mailsheet - and that's when it breaks. I need that reference to stay as the local sheet.

Comment: I'd agree with @cyboashu, its going to be much easier to get to the bottom of this if you include even partial code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an ActiveX button

which requires its associated code to be in the worksheet it resides in and that after that `.Copy` and `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ...` statements will point to the worksheet in newly created workbook

`Mail_FinishedSheet_Array()` Sub must also be in the new workbook if you want to make it independent from "Checkbook.xlsm". In this case  that Sub must reside in one of the two worksheets (`Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value` or "Z-MISC") being copied in the new workbook

Comment: Spot on - much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

user3598756 nailed it. Using an ActiveX button and then assigning the macro to it directly (right click, view code) has worked perfectly.